# Computer starts by itself

Tags: boot, dual-boot

My computer (Lenovo T460s) sometimes starts by itself. I have a Ubuntu and Windows in a Dual Boot. Last night, I shut down my computer on Windows (correctly) and this morning I found that the battery was dead. After looking into syslog, I found that it booted at 02:56, in the middle of the night! No USB devices were attached and no charger. Since GRUB lists Ubuntu first, it booted.

I am not quite sure where to look at so I pasted the syslog of that time here: http://pastebin.com/sFtEBqnT

Where else can I look at why my system was booted?
Could you tell me what was wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If when you shut down your system, the network connection light on your network adapter remains on and your router is left on, then the reason for this, is **Wake on LAN**.  Since you had shut your system down from Windows, you have to go to your network card settings on Windows and disable it so that your network adapter is switched off too when you shut down your system.

Comment: I didn't use the Ethernet port, the lights of the Ethernet port are off too.